# fetching users information from social networks

Tags: spring-social

I am kind of new when it comes to fetching users data from social networks, 
i need to extend my application and develop some kindof users data collector module
which in generally will be responsible for fetching data on my application users from social networks.

lets assume i have a user X which sign into my application with his facebook account.

can i fetch data on user X from facebook social graph only when he logged into ( my application/ facebook / both/ when ever i want )?

i was reading a beat on spring social framework, at first look it seems exactly the framework i need for my module.
the thing is that in all the examples i saw that each time fetching is required the user should manually allow it or it might be every time he logged into the application , also when looking at the code i think i saw that for each user a service provider
should be created, all the examples implies that spring social **is not ment** for background daemon which will fetch users data with minimal users attention.
**does spring social can answer my requirements?
there are other java open source options?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Social to access a social network on a user's behalf as long as you have a valid OAuth authentication token for that user. It's up to the provider (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, etc.) to dictate how long the tokens remain valid and how you can get new valid tokens. You'll have to read the provider's documentation to determine if the kind of background access you want is allowed by the provider. If it is allowed by the provider, than you ought to be able to use Spring Social to perform the operations you want to perform.

One example is Facebook. Facebook used to let you ask for a permission called "offline_access" which would result in your application receiving an authentication token for the user that would never expire (or at least wouldn't expire for a long time). They are deprecating this, though. For more information about Facebook specifically check this thread on the Spring Social forums:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123685-Facebook-offline_access